# Private key JWT with Keycloak and Acitve Directory gives a Client assertion failed signature validation in AD

Tags: azure-active-directory, jwt, keycloak, private-key

Set up Private key JWT in Keycloak but when trying to sso login gets an authentication error from Azure Active directory

Created a client and an oidc identity Provider in KC
In the provider added all the mandatory values

In the client, under Credentials tab chose signed jwt.
Generated new keys and certificate from the Keys tab

Added this certificate to Active directory.

When trying to SSO login from the application, gets the 'Unexpected error when authenticating with identity provider' error.
And in AD it shows the following error

```
Sign-in error code  
700027
Failure reason  
Client assertion failed signature validation.
Additional Details  
Developer error - the app is attempting to sign in without the necessary or correct authentication parameters.
```

Was following the section 'Signed JWT' in the doco to set it all up - https://www.keycloak.org/docs/18.0/server_admin/#_client-credentials

Comment: https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/issues/19425

Answer (score 0):

When selecting the  realm in the Admin Console.

And when Clicked Add keystore ,make sure to select  **rsa-generated.**

[image]

**Note** that ,the private key file should be  **PEM formatted**.

If Keycloak application is running behind some proxy server ,make sure the  path for `X.509` Client Certificate is set. Otherwise it might not allow to  import configuration.

Make sure the this certificate is not expired:

[image]

Make sure the correct Application Id uri is passed for the keycloak in azure ad
Format:

AppId uri: **`https://<>/auth/realsm/test`**

[image]

Reference : [Azure AD iDP with Keycloak as SP. Creating a Directory inside Azure: - | by Surya Prakash Pandey | Medium](https://suryaprakash-pandey.medium.com/azure-ad-idp-with-keycloak-as-sp-1ca933d71388)

Comment: Thanks @kavyaS We generated the rsa key, but there isn't an option to get the private key. Is it that private key that needs to go in AD?