# Configure Keycloak for private key JWT authentication

Tags: java, authentication, jwt, keycloak, private-key

I am working on authentication using X509 certificates. I need to call an endpoint which gives me some authentication token.

The request that I need to prepare to hit the endpoint has client_assertion as one of its parameters(besides others). The client_assertion itself is JWT token(with parameters like iss, aud, sub, iat, jti, etc) that I can prepare with JSON creation in java using some library and then encoding JSON object with the private key of the certificate using RS256 algorithm. This will give me a JWT token that I can use as client_assertion in the request body needed to hit the endpoint

With some research I came to know that this form of authentication is known as Private key JWT authentication wherein you have to prepare a client_assertion(a JWT token using some parameters) and then use this client_assertion JWT token to invoke another endpoint which gives you authentication token.

However to set this up in my local system, I need to get an endpoint that I can call to get authentication token. With some research, I came to know that Keycloak does have this functionality. However I couldn't figure out how to setup Keycloak for this i.e. what parameters need to be set and where.

I have gone through a lot of articles but looks like I am unable to link the dots.

Can anyone point me to some good example where this setup has been demonstrated?

AS an example I went through the following article but could not find the exact way
https://wjw465150.gitbooks.io/keycloak-documentation/content/securing_apps/topics/oidc/java/client-authentication.html

Also tried the link https://www.keycloak.org/docs/18.0/server_admin/#_client-credentials mentioned in this post: [Private key JWT with Keycloak and Acitve Directory gives a Client assertion failed signature validation in AD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75552569/private-key-jwt-with-keycloak-and-acitve-directory-gives-a-client-assertion-fail). However, it gives 404

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.